# What is the best approach for relatively rare as3/php/mysql interaction

Tags: php, mysql, xml, actionscript-3

I am writing an application with a Flex/as3 client. The client needs to send some data (at this point an xml file roughly 10 KB but later could balloon to up to 100 KB) to the server every minute or so and then receive another similar xml file back. The server's job is to validate the data in the xml file and possibly update a mysql database. Some other Flex/as3 clients that are in the same "group" as the client which sends data (and clients can join/leave a group anytime) need to be notified when the server processes the xml file so they can then chose whether to download the file. There can be several such groups of clients (and clients from different groups don't talk to each other). Since I am somewhat familiar with php I would prefer to use this for the server-side script.

My questions are the following:

1) Would it be best to write this as a socket application? Or should this be just POST data sent to a web script?

2) If this is sent to a web script as just some POST data, how can I ensure that other clients get notified? Do I just ping my script every few seconds (sounds resource intensive)...

3) Is there some framework/libraries that I should use (on client or server side) to facilitate developing this?

I appreciate your help,

Ilya

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use a socket connection. Normal POST data will be both slow and taxing. If you insist on it, I've done it before and can tell you how, but ultiamtely this should be easier: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfb.html

Comment: XML socket is actually what I thought I'd need to do but wanted to confirm since the update frequency is pretty low. For XML socket, is there some framework/libraries that you would suggest or is XMLsocket class enough for what I need? Thank you!